# Linked Lists in C: How possible is an OO design?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I'm working on implementing a dynamic linked list in C just to brush up on my C skills.
Here is the simple struct I use to represent a LinkedList:

```
typedef struct List
{
   Node_t* head;
   Node_t* tail;
   uint32_t length;
   void (*add)(Node_t* head, void* data);
} List_t;
```

I'm writing this all in its own C file with the hopes that I could include it in some other C file and use the linked list implementation I wrote.

You'll notice I have a pointer to a function that will add a node to the linked list.  (I have several functions other than add, but I just wanted to figure this one out first)

If I were to use this linked list right now, I would have to call it as such

```
List_t* list = GetList(); /* this is a constructor like method I wrote*/
list->add(list->head, someData);
```

Is it possible to code it in an OO fashion so that all I would have to do is call:

```
list->add(someData);
```

Without passing in the head of the list to the add() function?  My instincts tell me that it isn't possible, but I really like the idea of making my linked lists work that way.

-Akron

Edit: Corrected the reference to add to reflect the fact that list is a pointer

Edit: Looks like the general consensus is no.  Thanks for the tips/answers

Comment: It is probably possible with the use of macros, but it might not be pretty, or flexible.

Comment: I don't think you want to pass `list->head` to your `list.add()` method: you should pass the `List_t` structure instead, so you can also modify your `list->tail` member too. (If the list is empty, you'll need to modify both `list->head` and `list->tail`.)

Comment: @sarnold: Thank you for that point.  I definitely should do that

Comment: you also need that to update the length. if you want to insert at arbitrary position you'll still need a Node_t* parameter though.

Comment: Times like these make me realize how easy it is to rely upon [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)) from the high-level languages I use occasionally.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856749/malloc-and-free-with-a-dynamically-changing-structure/7856802#7856802

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing **is** an OO design.

What you are asking for is syntactic sugar to make your C code look like code in some other language.

I would advise you to stop fighting the language you are using, and instead concentrate on writing good, idiomatic code.

The idiomatic C way for would be to have a function like

```
void List_Add(List_t *list, void *data);
```

And then your client code would just call it like:

```
List_Add(list, someData);
```

Comment: Ok, I guess there is no way to do it then short of rewriting the compiler. (Which Im certainly not going to do)

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: No, had C++ on my mind.

Personally, when I use linked lists I prefer to have a function like `list_add(my_list, node)`, rather than try to make my code look all OO. You can make things abstract in a sense in C, but if I wanted to make my code really OO I'd just use C++.

Comment: The add method has parameters (Node_t* head, void* data).  When calling add(), it needs to know the head of the list.  What I'm really trying to figure out is some way to wrap this so when the List references the Add method that it points to, it automatically passes in its own head.

Comment: Yeah my bad, didn't look at it properly and was thinking of C++.